# cancelTouchesInView equivalent for NSGestureRecognizer

Tags: macos, gesture

UIGestureRecognizer has `cancelTouchesInView` flag, so if this flag is set to false, the view or its subview will still get tap events.

Is there any equivalent for NSGestureRecognizer (in particular NSClickGestureRecognizer)?

Comment: How about subclass and implement [`canPrevent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsgesturerecognizer/1534503-canprevent) and then return `true`?

Comment: Or implement delegate method [`gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsgesturerecognizerdelegate/1529773-gesturerecognizer)?